# What is the number of distinct subgroups of the automorphism group of $\mathbf{F}_{3^{100}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $G$ denote the group of all the automorphisms of the field $\mathbf{F}_{3^{100}}$ that consists of $3^{100}$ elements. What is the number of distinct subgroups of $G$?

Comment: I don't have any idea.

Answer (score 6):

Rhetorical questions:

- What is the order of $G(\Bbb F_{3^{100}}/\Bbb F_3)$?
- What kind of group is it?
- What are the subgroups of these kinds of groups?
- So, how many are there in this case?
- Are there any formulas for arithmetic functions of help here?

Comment: Why we need the order of $G(\Bbb F_{3^{100}}/\Bbb F_3)$?

Comment: @David Because you're going to use it to get the answer, of course. I've provided an itemized recipe as to how, you just need to follow the steps laid out for you: answer each bullet. If you don't know how to answer one of the bullets, ask for further help here in the comments.

Comment: Order is $3^{99}$. A galois field of order $3^{99}$. A sylow 3 group..

Comment: @Swap Huh? The order of ${\rm Gal}(\Bbb F_{3^{100}}/\Bbb F_3)$ is far from $3^{99}$, the order is not even a multiple of $3$. Where are you getting $99$ from? Or "sylow"? Your comment makes no sense at all to me.

Comment: Another interesting item might be: If $E/F$ is a Galois extension, what is the set of subgroups of $G(E/F)$ in (inclusion-reversing) bijection with?

Comment: Answer of question 
1) $100$ 2) It is a cyclic group

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

$\mathbf F_{3^{100}}=F_3[\alpha]$  for some *primitive element* $\alpha$. It is a root of an irreducible polynomial in $F_3[x]$ of degree $100$ and its conjugate are $\;\alpha,\alpha^3,\alpha^{3^2},\dots,\alpha^{3^{99}}$, which are all distinct since the polynomial is separable. Hence the Galois group $\;\operatorname{Gal}_{F_{3^{100}}/F_{3^{\phantom1}}}$ is cyclic of order $100$, generated by the *Frobenius morphism* $\;\varphi\colon x\mapsto x^3$. Its subgroups, as all subgroups of a cyclic group, are cyclic, generated by the $\varphi^n$, for all the divisors $n$ of $100$.

Answer (score 0):

Answer of question 
1) $100$ 
2) It is a cyclic group
3) Corresponding each divisor of $100$ there is a unique subgroup of $G(\Bbb F_{3^{100}} / \Bbb F_3)$
4) There are $9$ like this.
5) Its a sigma function. 
Now what?